# How do you bind keys in Eclipse's XML editor?

Tags: xml, eclipse, key

I have Eclipse Helios installed, using 
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools,
version 3.2.3.v201102160550-7H7AFUWDxumQJOi9ghcTb5YgkwEZ,
package org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
for XML editing.

I want to bind the Toggle Comment command (but it doesn't matter which), and I'm having trouble choosing a correct value for the "when" field. I tried "Structured Text Editors", "Text Editors", "XML Source editing", and even "In Windows", and my command still doesn't get picked up. The only other binding that uses the same shortcut is assigned for the same command in Java source editing. The command for Java works well.

So, how do I achieve this? Or,

- How can I determine the current context : it's not very clear to me how the current context (what you put in the when field whilst defining a shortcut) is determined, à priori it depends on the current editor, and if that editor doesn't have a particular context it uses it's parents one (AnEditor inherits? from Text Editor inherits from In Windows).
- is there anything to do in file associations? I'm still a bit confused by this compared to Windows own file/content associations, but in any case .xml is associated with the XML Source Editor, Text Editor, and I'm editing a real .xml file.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

OK it's all actually in the Help here : http://tinyurl.com/kdube46 (or just type 'Keys' in the Help searchbox).

Basically:

- current context is usually evidently defined : If you are editing Java code, your in the Editing Java Code context. This context extends it's father Editing Text, which extends In Windows, but your still in the Editing Java Code context. Extending here means just borrowing non-overridden parent bindings.
- Eclipse uses his file associations over Windows' I think (not sure). So no, file associations are correct. Actually the only way to achieve what I wanted, one binding for the same command under many contexts, is to associate all text files with Text Editor, it seems.

So currently no pleasant solution -> one binding per command per context.